# Are there public tools for developing homebrew Java games for the Nokia 2760?

Tags: java

The Nokia 2760 is a clamshell mobile phone released in 2007 which advertised its Java game support. Ten years ago it was still a very popular phone. There were a number of games either preinstalled or available as an add-on. But was/is it also possible to develop and run a homebrew game for this device? A quick search did not reveal that there are any development kits, tutorials, or similar.

Comment: Possibly Java ME but whether you can get the 2nd edition or whether the current edition will work on your phone is something else.  Have a look at https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javameoverview.html

Comment: There is some kind of Nokia Developer's Suite for Linux available here, which sounds somewhat like what you are looking for: https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38465
however it requires Forum Nokia account to proceed with the installer. Forum Nokia seems be off for some years, so you'll have to figure out how to unpack the installer and get its contents to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to unpack the installer I mentioned in question's comments and figured out how to launch NDS. You can grab it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PkkydZardCG1pPJg4gFWHATL2PJVSWjs/view?usp=sharing). To start (on Linux - for Windows you might need to use different directory separators), go to `MIDP_Products/NDSforJ2ME/core` in command line and run `java -classpath ./NDS_MIDPToolSet.jar:./jhall.jar com.nokia.phone.tools.midp.ui.StandAlone ./modules ./lib`. It wants to have older Java version (1.4.1) and throws some IOException at startup, but actually launches.

Since this is as far from proper install as it can get, some extra steps will be necessary to get everything working as expected (for example both bundled emulators fail to run anything because of some error with MIDI and you might have to set permissions on executables yourself).

I didn't have much time to tinker with it more, but if I do, I will update this answer.